# Angular: Get hash from filename for style switcher

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I have an Angular 6 app that uses webpack, and in this app I have a stylesheet switcher feature that will swap the stylesheet that is loaded. The problem is these stylesheets once compiled in production mode contain hashes in the filename (my-style.04beaf113c990fa3d2ba.css for example) so I am unable to accurately load the correct stylesheet since I don't know the correct hash up front.

Is there a way in the typescript to detect what this hash is so it will load the correct stylesheet?

My stylesheet switcher code is as follows:

```
  import { Directive, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

  @Directive({
    selector: '[wuToggleHighContrast]',
    host: {'class' : 'high-contrast-toggle'}
  })
  export class WuHighContrastDirective implements OnInit {
    linkTag: any;

    ngOnInit() {
      let hc = localStorage.getItem('webui_highContrast');
      if (hc) {
        this.enableHC();
      }
    }

    @HostListener('click')
    toggleHighContrast() {
      if (document.getElementById("wuHighContrast")) {
        this.disableHC();
      } else {
        this.enableHC();
      }
    }

    private enableHC() {
      const head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      this.linkTag = document.createElement('link');
      this.linkTag.rel = 'stylesheet';
      this.linkTag.id = 'wuHighContrast';
      this.linkTag.href = 'high-contrast.css';
      head.appendChild(this.linkTag);
      localStorage.setItem('webui_highContrast', 'true');
    }

    private disableHC() {
      document.getElementById("wuHighContrast").outerHTML = "";
      localStorage.removeItem('webui_highContrast');
    }
  }
```

I still want the cache busting that the hashes provide, but not sure how to correctly link to the stylesheet with the hash applied.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular CLI, it support to disable hashing when generating production build.
ng build --prod --output-hashing none

Comment: Thank you but I still need hashing to help with cache busting so this isn't an option for me.